# css framework and color schemes

Tags: css, colors, color-scheme, blueprint-css

I can't find a CSS frameowrk that lets me plugin my own color scheme.

For example, in my current project I imported blueprint/screen.css. To change the color of the font, I have to change body { color..}, h2 { color..}, h3 {color..}, etc.

Isn't there something out there that provides nice css defaults, but also lets may play around with color schemes?

Comment: thirtydot: can you make your comment about lesscss.org an answer, I want to upvote it!

Comment: Sure, no problem :) Also, you need to make sure you write `@username`, or there isn't a comment notification. I only noticed your comment because I happened to check back here.

Answer (score 4):

You can try http://lesscss.org/.

It allows you to use things such as variables in your CSS, which sounds like exactly what you're after:

```
// LESS

@color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
  color: @color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own CSS file that loads after Blueprint.  You'll need to redefine everything, but the Blueprint defaults aren't far off from the browser defaults.

If you have multiple color schemes you want to quickly switch out, set the class on your **<html>** tag.  Then use your CSS file to define custom styles for each.

CSS:

```
.theme1 body {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: #500;
}

.theme2 body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #050;
}
```

For the first theme:

```
<html class="theme1">
```

For the second theme:

```
<html class="theme2">
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking of doing, but it seems like a terrible way to solve a problem (I realize there may not be another way).

Comment: I'm using grep/sed to extract all css attributes involving color and am going to put them in a css file of their own. Not elegant, but should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just edit the blueprint/screen.css file? You could also use something like SASS and then create all the defaults at the top of the stylesheet and then have it go throughout the stylesheet when it renders it.